# Whats wrong with ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to JOIN two tables to one result in Google Sheet:

```
A, B, C, D
16.12.2022  "AAA"   16.12.2022  "BBB"
17.12.2022  "AAA"   17.12.2022  "BBB"
18.12.2022  "AAA"   18.12.2022  "BBB"


=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:B3; SVERWEIS(A1:A3; C1:D3; 1; FALSCH)})
```

Unfortunately I get the error:
"In ARRAY_LITERAL, an array literal is missing values in one or more rows."

Thanks...

Update:
Proposal 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:B3; SVERWEIS(A1:A3; {C1:C3, D1:D3}; {1,2}; FALSCH)})
```

Same Error

Proposal 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:B3\IFNA(SVERWEIS(A1:A3; C1:E3; 2))})
```

This works

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:B3; SVERWEIS(A1:A3; {C1:C3, D1:D3}; {1,2}; FALSCH)})
```

I only get column 1.

[image]

Why does this not work?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:B3; SVERWEIS(A1:A3; C1:E3; 2; FALSCH)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:B3\IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A3; C1:D3; 2;))})
```

***OR***

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(hstack(A1:B3;IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A3; C1:D3; 2;))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried your first proposal and it works, thanks! But I don't understand 1. Why without \IFNA not, 2. What means \ and 3. Why I only get still one column as result using {1,2} instead of 2?

Comment: [this article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/) here details the use of syntax used in semicolon convention sheets

Comment: This was the important hint...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, this helped me really. For who is interested here my solution for german location.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:B4\IFNA(SVERWEIS(A1:A4; C1:E4; {2\3}; FALSCH); "Error")})
```